# Procedure on update data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I have this tables and 1 procedure on update data...

```
CREATE sequence DIR_ID_SEQ;
create table DIRECTORS (
ID_DIR INTEGER DEFAULT DIR_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
DIRECTOR_CODE INTEGER DEFAULT DIR_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
SURNAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY_CODE INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT  PK_ID_DIR PRIMARY KEY (ID_DIR)
)
TABLESPACE TBS_PERM_KINO;
----------
CREATE sequence COUNTRY_ID_SEQ;
CREATE TABLE COUNTRY (
ID_COUNTRY INTEGER DEFAULT COUNTRY_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR2(200) NOT NULL,
COUNTRY_CODE INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT  PK_ID_COUNTRY PRIMARY KEY (ID_COUNTRY)
)
TABLESPACE TBS_PERM_KINO;
----------
alter table DIRECTORS add constraint FK_DIR_CODE_REF_ID_COUNTRY foreign key (DIRECTOR_CODE) references COUNTRY (ID_COUNTRY);
----------
create or replace procedure UpdateDirector(P_ID DIRECTORS.ID_DIR%TYPE,P_SURNAME DIRECTORS.SURNAME%TYPE,P_NAME IN DIRECTORS.NAME%TYPE,P_COUNTRY IN DIRECTORS.COUNTRY%TYPE,P_COUNTRY_CODE IN DIRECTORS.COUNTRY_CODE%TYPE)
is
begin
    UPDATE DIRECTORS SET ID_DIR = P_ID,
        SURNAME = P_SURNAME,
            NAME = P_NAME, COUNTRY = P_COUNTRY, 
                COUNTRY_CODE = P_COUNTRY_CODE 
                    WHERE DIRECTORS.ID_DIR = P_ID;
    exception
    when others 
    then DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
----------
BEGIN 
UpdateDirector(7,'TEST','TESTING','MEXICO',2);
END;
```

when i run UpdateDirector, with country and country_code which is not in COUNTRY table it works fine, but it shouldn't, i need to change my procedure, so that it checks for the validity of the input COUNTRY and CONTRY_CODE, can you tell me how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a referential constraint:

```sql
ALTER TABLE DIRECTORS
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_COUNTRY_CODE_REF_ID_COUNTRY foreign key (COUNTRY_CODE)
    REFERENCES COUNTRY (ID_COUNTRY);
```

Then do not **store** the `COUNTRY` column in the `DIRECTORS` table as that duplicates data that is stored elsewhere in the `COUNTRY` table, violates 3NF and as the data changes potentially leads to the two tables becoming out-of-sync.

If you want to **display** the country's name then you can use a `JOIN` to get that data from the `country` table as it is needed.